# Evaluate an if expression and then return the same evaluation if false in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I want to evaluate a from in if binding of clojure and if it returns false then i want to return the evaluation.

For eg

```
(defn testa [testvalue](let [tval testvalue]
                    (assert (validate tval) "incorrectvalue")
                    (if (= (+ 4 tval) 8)
                      1
                      (+ 4 tval))))
```

So here validate is a function which validates some criteria but after that if expression results in false then i am returning  the same result of the same expression i evaulated in if binding.But i want to avoid it writing again.

How can i do that?

Correction:- i also want to perform operation on tval before validate.

```
(defn testa [testvalue]
(let [tval (trim testvalue)] 
(assert (validate tval) "incorrectvalue") 
(if (= (+ 4 tval) 8) 
1 
(+ 4 tval))))
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just for fun:

```
(defn testa [testvalue]
  (assert (validate testvalue) "incorrectvalue")
  (as-> (+ testvalue 4) v
        (if (== v 8) 1 v)))
```

in repl:

```
user=> (testa 10)
14
user=> (testa 4)
1
```

upd: updated according to op's comment to another answer.

let's say you prepare your testvalue somehow with the `prepare` function. Then the whole function may look like this:

```
(defn testa [testvalue]
  (as-> (prepare testvalue) v
        (do (assert (validate v) "incorrectvalue")
            v)
        (+ v 4)
        (if (== 8 v) 1 v)))
```

it works like this:

```
v = prepare(testvalue);
assert(validate(v), "incorrectvalue");
v = (+ v 4);
if (v == 8)
  return 1;
else
  return v;
```

Answer (score 1):

Neal

I refactored and simplified to attain your desired result.

```
(defn testa [testvalue]
  (assert (validate testvalue) "incorrect value")
  (let [tval (+ 4 testvalue)]
    (if (= tval 8)
      1
      tval)))
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for reply.I forgot to mention,i am applying some evaluation on testvalue before i am asserting it.So lets say i am performing trim function on test value before assert.Then if i don't use let before assert,i will have to use trim  in while validating as well as in the let below it.So again i am using one function twice to perform same operation.Can this be resolved?

Comment: @Neel Edit your question to include any relevant information. However; moving the assert after the `let` and knowing what other preparation is done on the input value then yes it could be setup to perform once.